# SQL Concatenation using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
**ID    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5**    
1       abc   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    
2       ght   cde   NULL  NULL  NULL    
3       atr   dgf   aft   NULL  NULL     
4       asd   rty   tyu   xyz   NULL     
5       abc   pqr   xyz   rst   rty    
6       qwe   rty   ghj   rty   tyu
```

I want it change in this form:

```
**ID    NewCol**    
1   abc    
2   ght/cde    
3   atr/dgf/aft    
4   asd/rty/tyu/xyz    
5   abc/pqr/xyz/rst/rty    
6   qwe/rty/ghj/rty/tyu
```

The query I wrote is:

```
     SELECT ID,     
    NewCol = CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NULL THEN col1    
                WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL  AND col3 IS NULL THEN col1+'/' + col2    
                WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL AND col4 IS  NULL THEN col1+'/'+ col2 + '/' + col3    
                WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL AND col5 IS NULL THEN col1+'/' + col2 + '/' + col3+ '/' + col4     
                WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL AND col5 IS not NULL THEN col1+'/' + col2 + '/' + col3+ '/' + col4 + '/' + col5     
                ELSE NULL     
  END     
   FROM dbo.Temp
```

If we have like 10 columns then I thought may be this is not an efficient way to write this.
Can you help me find a better solution to this one?
Thanks.

Comment: use coalesce and concat a '' when null?  coalesce(col1,'')+'/'coalesce(Col2)+'/'... Then eliminate any trailing '/''s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is simpler:

```
select (col1 + coalesce('/' + col2, '') + coalesce('/' + col3, '') + 
        coalesce('/' + col4, '') + coalesce('/' + col5, '')
       )
```

This assumes that `col1` always has a value.

Comment: neat idea with the inner concat.

Comment: I like the '/'+col2 results in null  when colx is null.  And then null gets set to empty string on coalesce  Clean.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
col1 + concat('/' + col2, '/' + col3, '/' + col4, '/' + col5)
```

If on 2012 or later  version